# Getting an error, while building Digikam source in linux

Tags: c++, qt

```
CMake Error at /Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.6/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:16 (message):
  The imported target "Qt5::Core" references the file

     "/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.6/qtbase/../../../Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.6/qtbase//mkspecs/linux-g++"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/amount/shotgun_home/sprasad/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.6/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfigExtras.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.
```

Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Please do some investigation, such as if you have that file somewhere.

Comment: Can you tell us what steps you took? It seems you are referencing the Qt source tree for some reason. Normally you install a package for Qt and reference that when building.

Comment: 1) It is a downloaded qt package "qt-everywhere-src-5.12.6". The package build successfully.

2) while building Digikam package using cmake getting the error.
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debugfull -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix` ..

3) /Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.6/qtbase//mkspecs/linux-g++
    folder exists

4) during build process, it executes 
"/Downloads/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.6/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake"
there it sets 
set(Qt5Core_VERSION_STRING 5.12.6)
set(Qt5Core_LIBRARIES Qt5::Core)

Comment: macro(_qt5_Core_check_file_exists file)
    if(NOT EXISTS "${file}" )
        message(FATAL_ERROR "The imported target \"Qt5::Core\" references the file
the above macro fails.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61768
as per this link suggestion i have followed, that resolved the above error.

Thank you